# SciPy Derivative Function - Argument Parsing Failure

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the derivative of a function with the scipy derivative module. Unfortunately I cant parse my argument into the function without a TypeError:

```
def f(x, *arg):
    beta = arg
    y = -x + beta * np.tanh(x)
    return y

param = (0,)
der_x0 = derivative(f, x0 = 0.0, dx = 1e-6, args = param)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

`beta` is of type tuple (try e.g. to add `print(beta)` after `beta = arg` and you should see something like `(0,)` as printout instead of `0`).

Try:

```
beta = arg[0]
```

instead, i.e.

```py
def f(x, *arg):
    beta = arg[0]
    y = -x + beta * np.tanh(x)
    return y
```

and you should get a value of `-1.0` for `der_x0`.

Comment: thank you for your instructive answer. It worked perfectly.